# How to escape a character in bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex

I am creating a bytearray from a list.

```
mybytes_array = bytes([255,110,41,128,09])
```

I then uses regex to find all occurences of

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(mybytes_array, ba)]
```

I can have any value instead of 41 that creates a metacharacter for regex. I want to escape that character so that I can match it against `ba` that is also a bytearray

How can I do that?

I cannot obviously convert to string append backslash and then match against ba. So I am not sure how can I change the mybytes_array so as to search the correct string.

Comment: Convert it to a string, call `re.escape()`, then convert it back to bytes?

Comment: Any example of `ba`?

Comment: Thank you Barmar. It solved my issue. It might be Aaron's solution will also work. Still have to test.

Answer (score 0):

The `re` package can work on both `str` and `bytes` inputs as long as the arguments are of the same type.

You may use `re.escape` to escape the whole `bytes`.

Your code will be something like

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(re.escape(mybytes_array), ba)]
```